# My PartialView is causing my application to breakdown everytime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to load my partial view with some data from database, but I'm getting following issue when I run the application:

> Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.

I don't know why this is happening because I'm pretty new with MVC technology.

Here is my `PartialViewResult` method in a controller:

```
public PartialViewResult UnReadEmails()
{
   if (User.Id != null)
   {
      List<Emails> resultList = EmailController.GetUnreadEmailsByUserId(User.Id);
       return PartialView("~/Views/Emails/_UnReadEmails.cshtml", resultList);
   }
   return PartialView("Error, not found!");
}
```

And here is my partialview itself, it is called _UnReadEmails (as you can see I'm displaying here info about sender and email body), PartialView is retrieving list of Emails that I'm sending to from my Controller

```
@model IEnumerable<Emails>

foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <a>
            <span>
               <span>@item.EmailSender</span>
               <span class="email">
                     @item.Body;
               </span>
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

After I tried to load my partial view on this way:

`@Html.Action("UnreadEmails", "Message")`

I started to receive following issue that I mentioned in my Title,

I already tried few things to solve this like changing `@Html.Action("UnreadEmails", "Message")` to `@Url.Action("UnreadEmails", "Message")` etc etc but that didn't solve my issue.

EDIT: It allways breaks on this line (on view) :

`@Html.Action("UnreadEmails", "Message")`

It never goes into code behind.. [image]

After Chris suggestion on another post I added `[AllowAnonymous]` on the top of the method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public PartialViewResult UnReadEmails()
{
   if (User.Id != null)
   {
      List<Emails> resultList = EmailController.GetUnreadEmailsByUserId(User.Id);
       return PartialView("~/Views/Emails/_UnReadEmails.cshtml", resultList);
   }
   return PartialView("Error, not found!");
}
```

EDIT EDIT EDIT:

Interesting fact is that whatever I wrote in my Controller's method and even if I comment all code, it will still break on a View, that means it will never came into a Controller's method. I put breakpoing there at the begining of the UnReadEmails method and it was never hitted, it allways breaks on a View!

EDIT AFTER MAURIZIO suggestion to change it to `@Html.RenderPartial`
Than I received following issue:

> The partial view 'UnReadEmails' was not found or no view engine
>   supports the searched locations. The following locations were
>   searched: ~/Views/Dashboard/UnReadEmails.aspx
>   ~/Views/Dashboard/UnReadEmails.ascx ~/Views/Shared/UnReadEmails.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/UnReadEmails.ascx ~/Views/Dashboard/UnReadEmails.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Dashboard/UnReadEmails.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/UnReadEmails.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/UnReadEmails.vbhtml

EDIT:

Compiler Error Message: CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MessageController.UnReadEmails()'

I tried to make UnReadEmails() as static but than I received following error :

> Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.PartialView(string,
>   object)'  ...Controllers\Message\MessageController.cs

Comment: Have you try using @Html.RenderPartial("UnreadEmails", "Message") ?

Comment: what is that parameter "Message" used for ? is the error (void ->object) shown on one of the parameters of the RenderPartial method ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Check for Edit my friend, I adeed { } braces and that solved void-> object issue. But there is another issue after I applied RenderPartial

Comment: What is the name of your Controller?

Comment: @RMadd The name of a controller is MessageController

Comment: OK then use `@Html.Action("UnreadEmails", "MessageController")`.

Comment: @RMadd if you red my question carefully you might see that I've used that all the time and it didn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your partial view is not in the Shared folder you need to provide the full path

```
{@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Emails/_UnReadEmails.cshtml")}
```

Since that view needs the list of emails you need to add that as parameter

```
{@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Emails/_UnReadEmails.cshtml",EmailController.GetUnreadEmailsByUserId(User.Id))}
```

The best aproach would be to create a property in the Model (`List<Emails> lstUnreadEmails`) and load that list of emails in a method of the `MessageController`, so that the information is ready for the partial to be render with this instruction:

```
{@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Emails/_UnReadEmails.cshtml",Model.lstUnreadEmails)}
```

In case you dont have a "main model" you could store that in a `ViewBag`, calling this from a MessageController method

```
ViewBag.lstUnreadEmail‌s = E‌​mailController.Get‌‌​​Un‌​readEmailsByUserId(U‌​ser.Id);
```

And in the View use this

```
{@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Emails/_UnReadEmails.cshtml",ViewBag.lstUnreadEmail‌​s)}
```

Comment: can you check my EDIT please.

Comment: check also the last part of my answer, since is not a good practice to call controller method from views.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro do not confuse the new property that I suggest (lstUnreadEmails) with the method UnreadEmails that you seem to be using

Comment: this approach seems to be a good one because there is no error when I tested it with an empty list, but I think I can not do this : Model.lstUnreadEmails because there is no Model in this PartialView where I'm trying to load my partialView... so I am wondering how could I send a list to my partial view, following your second suggestion where method needs to be a static I'm receiving an error that I  explained in EDIT of my Question.

Comment: So this approach failed too ? {@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Emails/_UnReadEmails.cshtml",EmailController.GetUnreadEmailsByUserId(User.Id))}, maybe you could update your question with the added code

Comment: if I want to implement that approach, I need to change my UnreadEmails method to a  static UnreadEmails but then I received issues, I will post image in a sec so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145653/discussion-between-mauricio-gracia-gutierrez-and-roxypro).

Comment: hey my friend, when I publish this I am facing issues, I can not use path like "~/Views.." because on my publish server I have several subsites and it's looking into root and there is no this path, so I'm afraid I must use another method where I should pass method name and a controller :/

Comment: try relocating the View into "~/Views/Shared/" and use "_UnReadEmails" as the first parameter of the RenderPartial (consider also removing the initial underscore from the partial name and from the first parameter also)